# USB device not recognized constantly showing

Tags: windows-10, usb

My PC was working great. I turned it off yesterday and back on today and I have an issue with a USB device.

When Windows starts, it keeps telling me that the

> USB device not recognized
>   The last USB device you connected to this computer malfunctioned, and Windows does not recognize it.
>   Windows Explorer

I also get a little notification in the action center.

Within 1 or 2 seconds, the message disappears, as does the message in the action center. 5 seconds later, the messages are back and this doesn't end.

[image]

Thinking this should be easy to fix via the power of elimination, I removed the USB devices. The same issue occurs. I then removed the Firewire devices as well. Same issue.

I then open up Device Manager. The device manager window/application refreshes totally as the USB device is not recognized message pops up, but never do I see the yellow exclamation mark by any device to give me a hint.

The problem I think I'm going to have is finding out what the device is because, as per the message, Windows doesn't recognize it.

I've not installed any new software/hardware for quite some time.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Is it a notebook? They often have internal USB devices.

Comment: @DanielB, no, it's a PC... Although, now you've said that one of my PCI cards does have an internal USB which I didn't think of. Can you please move your comment to an answer. Whilst it's probably not *the* answer it's worth the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the answer was to do nothing!

After 30 minutes it just stopped! So, not a particularly good result as no cause was identified but I'll leave this in case it helps others.

Comment: This is a sign that something is flaky with some of your USB devices. Next time please use this utility [link](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-device-tree-viewer-download)   to see all USB tree and status of all connected (and failed, if any) USB devices in your computer.

Comment: @AliChen, can you move your comment to the main post so I can upvote?

Comment: Did you try the USBview utility? So, what did you see? Are there any internal USB devices that could be responsible for generating that message?